# about _id and nested objects

Tags: mongodb

I would appreciate it if somebody could answer my newbie MongoDB questions.

1. What will be consequences if user assigned _id field won't be unique
   in DB or collection? In what scope uniqueness is really necessary
   (and what is the scope for nested objects)?
2. Is it possible to change (replace) _id (and its type) for the whole documents in the collection?
3. what is the difference (in handling by DB engine) between nested objects when I store just as json objects (see below - A) or as embedded documents with _id (B)?

   A) `{book: _id:.. chapters[{json object has not _id},{}]}`

   B) `{book: _id:.. chapters[{_id:... },{}]}`

   Is the difference just in presence of _id and indexing or something deeper?
4. How can I convert "just json objects"(without _id) to embedded documents with _id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What will be consequences if user assigned _id field won't be unique
>   in DB or collection? In what scope uniqueness is really necessary (and
>   what is the scope for nested objects)?

Uniqueness is too important in any data set, because you need a way to identify your data by  some identity. Unique ids are key for this.

And it is really important when you define a unique indexes. It will be screwed when  you try to add duplicate key in the unique index.

> Is it possible to change (replace) _id (and its type) for the whole
>   documents in the collection?

No its not possible in a straight way, you need to copy the document data to temp collection and reinsert them into the original collection with the new ids.

> what is the difference (in handling by DB engine) between nested
>   objects when I store just as json objects (see below - A) or as
>   embedded documents with _id (B)?

Embedded objects are the ones natively supported by mongodb, the referencing objects will be handled manually by your code mostly by the ODMs (like ruby Mongoid)

Since you asked the difference, Embedded documents are treated like a another field in the document so you can query it, you can index it and will be returned as part of the document.

But the referencing documents are entirely a separate document. You can't directly query it from the parent doc and so the indexing. Instead you have to write the application logic to store ids and manually query them from the application.

> How can I convert "just json objects"(without _id) to embedded
>   documents with _id?

<strike>Your assumption is wrong. Embedded documents do have ids. It will be automatically generated when you create one.</strike>

**EDIT:**

My assumptions were wrong in this. Mongodb does not auto generate the ids for embedded documents. But some ODM's like Mongoid generate ids for embedded documents too.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, Ramesh. But I didn't get about just objects without. You say all objects {} will have _id automatically?  MongoidBook.new({:title=>"NewBook", :brief=>{:history=>"old"},items:[{:name=>"Alex"}]}) object brief and item[0] do not have and _id field. Maybe I misunderstand something?

Comment: @WHITECOLOR, thats strange, will you update your post with your model definition... and which driver you are usinh?

Comment: Well in Rubby I have definition mongoid model only for Book collection object. But I've got the same result for standard Mongo console insert: books.insert({title:"SuperBook",brief:{history:"new"},items:[{name:"Alex"}]} - brief and item are without _id

Comment: @WHITECOLOR, yes you are right. my assumptions were wrong. Ids not auto generated for embedded docs. The ids auto generated when using mongoid.

Comment: Yes, what i see is that by mongo engine _id auto generated only on root documents but not embedded docs, its actually just a certain field that got indexed automatically. I wonder if  "_id" field is defined by user for embedded docs its indexed automatically, i believe not, this feature only for root, and I wonder if mongoid does for embedded. What do you think? Documentation couldn't make it more clear for me =)

Comment: @WHITECOLOR, You are absolutely right, only _ids in root document are auto indexed. And even though mongoid auto generates  ids for embedded, its not creating any indexes on _ids. I am positive about it. i just tried with both shell and mongoid..